# Fatal error when installing gecode-python

Tags: python

I'm trying to install a python wrapper over constraint programming library Gecode called python-gecode
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gecode-python/
No matter how I install it I get same error "No such file or directory". Here is setup script output:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'gecode._gecode' extension
C:\MinGW32-xy\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -DDISJUNCTOR "-IC:\Program Files\Gecode\include" -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c _gecode.cc -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_gecode.o
_gecode.cc:5:24: fatal error: 4.2.1: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"
```

But the _gecode.cc is there in the folder. I don't really understand what's the problem. I tried installing with pip, easy_install, manual install and everytime I get this error.
Any ideas what's causing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have gcc installed in the location it is called from?

Comment: Yes. It's over here
C:\MinGW32-xy\bin\gcc.exe

Answer (score 1):

Gecode-Python supports only up to version 4.0.0 of Gecode, so use that version instead of 4.2.1.